# Time Tracking App with Alfred integration

Tags: software-recommendation, alfred

Is there a time tracking that integrates with [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/), so you can start/stop time tracking using typed commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [Harvest](http://getharvest.com) to track time. It has a robust API. There is a command-line tool called [hcl](http://zackhobson.com/hcl/) for interacting with Harvest time sheets.

I haven't bought the [Alfred Powerpack](http://www.alfredapp.com/powerpack/) myself, but I presume that since the Powerpack includes an interface to develop your own shell scripts to extend Alfred that it would be fairly straightforward to start/stop new tasks:

```
$ hcl start mytaskalias adding a new feature

$ hcl stop
```

You've inspired me to look into this for improving my workflow. I currently use the Harvest application which has a very handy menu bar control, but being able to start/stop a timer quickly from Alfred sounds like a nice option…

Answer (score 6):

I just released a workflow with this functionality.

- View details on the Alfred forum: http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/3166-harvest-time-tracking/
- Or view the project directly on Github: https://github.com/tinystride/alfred-harvest

Answer (score -2):

I’m not really sure if there’s a time tracking software that integrates with AlfredApp but take a look at this [project management app](http://blog.timedoctor.com/2011/04/23/project-management-with-google-%20%20apps) that has an integration with some useful Google applications, this might help you find a good alternative. In addition, most time trackers have an easy option to simply start/stop the timer. If you can find a software that requires you to simply enter a task name then that’s a good option to pick.